# Invalid HTTP response from webserver through port forward on modem

Tags: html, embedded, webserver, portforwarding, lwip

I'm currently building an embedded device that uses the open source light-weight IP package ([lwIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LwIP)) to host a static webserver to clients using html files and http requests. lwIP is somewhat different than a normal webserver because it is bare bones and configured to serve these files through a NOSYS declaration.

In an extremely simple scenario, I'm trying to host this file (`index.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello
  </body>
</html>
```

When I'm connected directly to the embedded device, I get headers from the webserver that are valid, like below:

```
Host: 192.168.168.10
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

and I can view the page no problem.

However, if I try to go through a modem that port forwards to the embedded device, I get the following error on Firefox when trying to view `index.html`:

```
The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range.
The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.
```

The odd thing is the headers are still the same (just a different ip and port):

```
Host: 192.168.2.31:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

and the response data is still the same as `index.html` above.

I don't understand what's causing the error, as the content type is specified in the  tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed through using Tom Vs suggestion of `curl -v` against the server. This gave a response of `Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed`.

When looking through the configuration of LWIP in `lwipopts.h`, `LWIP_HTTPD_DYNAMIC_HEADERS` was set to 0. This should be set to 1 to enable the headers to be generated from lwIP and set to the user.

Answer (score 0):

What you have pasted are the *request* headers that your browser sends to the server.  The problem is with the *response* headers that the embedded server sends back.  In particular the Content-Type header isn't correct.  It should look something like:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

You can work around this using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="...">` in the page if you can't see where to add them in the embedded application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did have that meta tag in the html file, but it won't load any response headers so I can't see what is invalid about the response. I find it odd that it works no problem without going through the modem though

Comment: Maybe try `curl -v` to see what response headers are present in each case.

Comment: I think you might have solved it, doing `curl -v 192.168.2.9:8080` gives response `Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed`. Looks like lwIP is serving files using HTTP 0.9 with no headers. 

I'll keep this question open a bit longer while I poke around, but somehow configuring lwIP for HTTP 1.0 or newer may be the fix.

Comment: Thanks Tom, `curl -v` helped isolate the problem. I was able to fix the headers being served by enabling `LWIP_HTTPD_DYNAMIC_HEADERS` within the config for lwIP. This was set to 0 from the sample I was using. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in `<head>` of your HTML document, it may resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately that doesn't fix my issue. It seems to be related to going through the modem, but I'm unsure how that should change anything about the request and response for the html file